# Implement list type as observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an interface

```
public interface IEmployee
{
   List<Job> Jobs{get;set;}
}
```

I want to implement it for my view model and do some binding on collection.How can I implement the same List as observable collection in implemented class

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
   ObservableCollection<Job> Jobs{get;set;}
   //this is giving error
}
```

I am not allowed to change interface as its implemented by other classes.How ever there is a need to display jobs in View and utilize collection changed notifications which is only available with observable collection.

Comment: You cant do that while they have same name. because you must implement List and not anything else.

Comment: do you mean you want to implement bindings on `IEmployee`? How is `IEmployee` currently notifying of changes?

Comment: Iam binding observable collection to view ,I need collection changed events thats why cant use list in Viewmodel.

Comment: @TRS Then why does your interface have `List<Job>`? Can you not use `ObservableCollection<Job>` in both your interface and your implementation?

Comment: No,I cant change interface,its implemented by other classes also.

Comment: @TRS Your interface promises that callers can, given an `IEmployee e`, give the employee a whole new list of jobs: `e.Jobs = new List<Job>();`. There's no way you're going to be able to make that work properly. You *may* be able to make it work properly if you give the interface a `get`-only property `Jobs` (and preferably give the implementation a `get`-only property too), but that's still a change in the interface.

Comment: If it's implemented by other classes as `List<Job>`, then change the interface to `ICollection<Job>`, because both `List` and `ObservableCollection` implement `ICollection`.

Comment: @IlyaKogan For data binding, it probably needs to be `IList<Job>` rather than `ICollection<Job>` (also implemented by both classes), but either way, lowing the type while keeping the property mutable seems dangerous.

Comment: keeping a `List` in your interface and using `ObservableCollection` in `Employee` seems very odd. It seems to me that you have a design flaw - if the interface says that it should be a list then why would the class need to implement anything other than that? If the class **needs** to be observable, then why isn't the contract enforcing it? it's contradictory!

Comment: For instance, what happens if the `IEmployee.Jobs` is changed? Should the implementers notify owners of it? If not, then maybe the `Employee.Jobs` should be named something else, and copy the `Jobs` from the interface to this new collection (which is observable) - still, a clunky solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `ObservableCollection<T>` does not inherit from `List<T>`. But you probably don't need a `List<T>` in the interface anyway. I think the `IEmployee` interface is not designed correctly. What do the users of `IEmployee` need from the list? If they only need to iterate over it, use `IEnumerable<Jobs>` in `IEmployee`.

If the users of `IEmployee` also need the `Count` property, you can declare `Jobs` as `ICollection<Jobs>` in `IEmployee`. `ObservableCollection<T>` does implement `ICollection<T>`

By the way, are you sure the class name is supposed to be `Jobs` and not `Job`? `Jobs` is a strange name for a class.

Comment: I need to bind Viewmodel collection to view and use collection changed events which is not possible with List.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I didn't suggest that you use `List`

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public JobCollection Jobs { get; set; }
    public Employee()
    {
        Jobs = new JobCollection();
    }
}

public class JobCollection : ObservableCollection<Job>
{

}
```

Comment: Cant change interface.

Answer (score -2):

This is the correctly solution:

```
public interface IEmployee
{
  ObservableCollection<Jobs> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't agree it's the most correct solution. The question is what the `IEmployee` contract needs. Do its users care that the collection is observable? If `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` are enough, they are better solutions.

Comment: The OP stated that the interface cannot be modified.